# Does Sasori control Sharingan-wielding puppets?

Tags: naruto

If you look at Naruto Shippuden Episode 26, in the episode, you can see that one of Sasori's puppets have the Sharingan in its eyes.

[image: this image]

Is there any reason for this?  Can one of Sasori's puppets use the Sharingan? Wouldn't a lot of chakra be used up to manage a Sharingan, and could Sasori manage that too?

Comment: if he was able to turn a kazekage into his puppet, i dont see how hard it is for him to possess an uchiha puppet

Answer (score 7):

Can a puppet made by Sasori use abilities like Sharingan?  **Yes,** provided that they were actually [Human Puppets](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Puppet).

> By removing the internal organs of a foe and preserving the body to prevent decomposition, as well as adding weapons and defences, Sasori can make powerful human puppets. These puppets are different from normal ones, **as they retain their use of chakra and any kekkei genkai** that the human host once had.

The likely scenario is that the chakra cost isn't incurred by Sasori himself, but rather by the puppet, so the abilities used by the puppet would be limited to the former original person's own chakra strength.  If they were actual members of the Uchiha clan before being transformed instead of shinobi which transplanted the eyes into themselves, then the likely case is that the chakra cost is negligible.

Interestingly enough, a handful of them (according to Narutopedia) are actually former Sharingan users, and are part of his Hundred Puppet Army (likely a part of what you're witnessing), although the fact that they have Sharingan isn't exploited in any media, according to any existing sources.

Comment: but isnt chakra the life force ? how can a dead shinobi still have chakra ?

Comment: It was never revealed how, but Sasori used a method of preservation that could turn living people into puppets while retaining their chakra and kekkai genkai

ref: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Puppet

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to original question is:

YES. He technicly could. And he potentially has multiple ones. Here's another scene from the fight (yes, it's a different scene, about 5 minutes later. Animation is expensive kids.)
[image]

As Bhagyesh mentioned in a comment, only living people have chakra, so in my head-cannon it works like that:

Each human is like a vessel, and chakra is like a fluid. Sasori's technique of creating human puppets allows puppets to retain original "chakra shape". so that when he channels chakra through them, it behaves in the same way it did when they were alive.

This is supported by Chiyo when she said that "3rd had a special body composure which allowed him to turn his chakra into magnetic forces", as well as the fact when 3rd kazekage got resurrected in war arc he was considerably stronger than his puppet form (presumably because of infinite chakra supply).

But. Why "technically" and "potentially?
Well Because his sharingan puppets are shown to be really really weak. And if they actually had sharingans I would imagine them being at least really good at hand to hand, and maybe able to cast some genjutsu at the very least.

So in my opinion, knowing that Sasori is master of deception It's very much possible, that he just painted sharingans onto wooden balls to look like actual sharingans just to make his puppets more terrifying (sharingan being pretty much the most feared kekkei genkai in the world).

So TL;DR He technically could have built Uchiha human puppets and use every single one of their jutsu, and at the same chakra price as OG Uchiha. But he probably didn't. They look and act as if they are just for show, so there is no reason to think that they have anything more behind them.